# Which Javascript function placement is better?

Tags: javascript, parsing, scope

I'm trying to build a game and I noticed that for organization it might be better to place some functions inside other functions because they are used in the original function exclusively. For example:

```
function fn1()
{
    fn2();

    function fn2()
    {
        //Stuff happens here
    }
}
```

`fn1` gets called many times, and `fn1` will call `fn2` several times in its execution. When `fn1` is called, does `fn2` have to be re-processed (for lack of a better word) every time? Am I losing out in terms of performance because of this? Should I place `fn2` after `fn1` instead, like this?

```
function fn1()
{
    fn2();
}

function fn2()
{
    //Stuff happens here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to achieve similar scoping, but only create one copy of `fn2`:

```
//Initiliaze before you call `fn1`:  
var fn1 = (function(){

    // This is the function assigned to fn1
    return function(){
        fn2();
    }

    function fn2()
    {
        //Stuff happens here
    }
})();
```

Compare the console output of these to fiddles, the former of which creates an extra copy of `fn2`, since a locally scoped `fn2` is created for each call to `fn1`: http://jsfiddle.net/A2UvC/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/A2UvC/3/

There are advantages to the additional copys of `fn2` however. They may have access to different variables like in the following situation:

```
function fn1(x){

    // Return an object exposing fn2 to the caller's scope
    return {fn2: fn2};

    // Each call to fn1 creates a new fn2 which has access 
    // to the closured `x` from the call to fn1 that created it
    function fn2(){
        console.log(x);
    }

}

var ex1 = fn1(1);
var ex2 = fn1(2);

ex1.fn2 == ex1.fn2; // true
ex1.fn2 == ex2.fn2; // false, because they are two distinct copies

ex1.fn2(); // 1
ex2.fn2(); // 2
ex2.fn2(); // 2
ex1.fn2(); // 1
```

Comment: Since you are not enclosing the function expression in parenthesis, maybe you want to explicitly point out that you are calling the outer function immediately. Relevant reading material: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/.

Comment: @FelixKling I added the parenthesis to make that more obvious.

Comment: +1 :-) Also, can you explain if the OP's 1st way creates multiple copies of fn2

Comment: I've been looking this over because I don't think I fully understand this correctly. In your first example, you're creating a function that returns a function, so that it can be 'injected' into any other function, correct? As for your second example, given that fn2 will be accessed exclusively by fn1, why not just define fn2 inside fn1 if I'm going to be making multiple copies anyway? Also, both those fiddles link to the same thing.